# Collection Type Property For User Control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, properties

Is it possible to create a user control with a list of custom class type property?
If it is, how can I?

The issue is that, in designer mode the property is not displayed in property window. I can add the list on markup but when i switch to the designer mode it gives an error which is 'The user control does not have a public property named BookList'.

Comment: Any clues to language, development environment, application?

Comment: I use VB.Net with Visual Studio 2010. I actually created a user control with a list of custom class type property. But the issue is that, in designer mode the property is not displayed in property window. I can add the list on markup but when i switch to the designer mode it gives an error which is 'The user control does not have a public property named BookList'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem that you have here is that your list property collection contains a custom class type.

You'll need to ensure that your custom collection class is declared public so that the designer can access it. You may need it to be declared within the same files as the custom control.

If the class contained within the collection is not easily displayed then you may also need to add a TypeConverter to the property and override GetStandardValuesSupported and GetStandardValues methods (maybe even GetStandardValuesExclusive too).